# Read a local Derby DB from Python

Tags: python, macos, derby

I'm trying to develop a Python script and at a given time I need to access a local (offline) Derby database to gather some info. To be exact I only need to read two fields in the DB. I'm constrained to use ONLY tools available on MacOSX out of the box! I am not allowed to install ODBC drivers nor other software than the system internal Java Packets.
That got me searching for the actual file structure of a Derby DB and I have found a document where more or less the directory structure is described ([Derby Documentation](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.0/manuals/develop/develop13.html)) but I have not been able to find any information about the DB itself within the Derby documentation.
Does anybody know of a Module for Python or a technical paper describing the on disc structure of the DB?

Here is what I have to do:
I have an app which reads documents from an Alfresco server into a directory (not written by me and without any documentation). The documents are named with the UUID on disk which is matched with the real filename in a table of the Derby DB. I need to develop a tool (quick 'n' dirty hack) to copy the files to another folder restoring their original filenames. Easiest for me is Python I guess, but other suggestions are welcome.

The DB will be OFFLINE and nobody is going to be accessing it at the time of reading, so I guess I don't have to worry about corruption.

Comment: Wow, this really seems like you're going about things the hard way. Python can do a lot, but frankly Derby's natural API is to use SQL from a Java JDBC application. Pretty much anything else is going to be extraordinarily painful.

Comment: I know, but unforunately I have the limitations to work only with software installed out of the box! Thing is, I do not have to be able to do queries or whatsoever on the DB, only need to read two fields of a table. Knowing the file structure, like header size and record size, it should be feasible...but I can't find any docs about it.

Comment: there are a few docs on the derby site, but mostly you'd be going from the source code. There is a "database recovery tool" for Derby that might give you some ideas about how to write your program. I still think you should consider re-framing your problem, though. It's not obvious to me how a Derby DB ended up on your system without a copy of Java on your system, too.

Comment: There IS a copy of Java on it, but it is encapsuled just for the APP that's downloading the stuff (beside Apple's very own Java implementation). I can't make any use of it though (at least I wouldn't know how). I will have a look into the docs and see how it goes...Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Best of luck. Here's some page format docs: http://db.apache.org/derby/papers/pageformats.html Regarding the Java question, pretty much any version of Java is enough to be able to run Derby's "ij" tool, which can open the database and select the fields from a row in the table.